# How to use LUNA HSM with Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, hsm

I am working on a spring boot application which needs to  communicate with another service through HTTPS connection using TLS certificates.
Earlier the requirements were not clear and I started using the Java Keystore/Truststore for the certificats and key pairs.
But later we decided to migrate to HSM Luna Client where we need to generate the certificates and public/private keys.

I have gone through the Luna documentation from Thales website on how we can generate the key pairs and csr files.

https://thalesdocs.com/gphsm/luna/7.2/docs/network/Content/sdk/java/java_keytool_with_luna_hsm.htm

But I do not understand How i can use these certificate in my java application for SSL/TLS connection.

Do I have to now use the JSP/JCPROV libraries. Or I can somehow add the keystore/truststore files in my java application classpath just like i did earlier.
The documentation does not depict any sample code on using the keystore/truststore.

I just want to make  HTTPS calls to another service using RestTemplate and recieve the response in my JAVA application.

Can someone please help me understand this. It would be better if someone can provide the code snippets as well.

I am posting my code below:

```
@Configuration
Class ApplicationConfig{
   
  static {
   com.safenetinc.luna.LunaSlotManager.getInstance().login("Partition-password");
   java.security.Provider provider = new com.safenetinc.luna.provider.LunaProvider();
   java.security.Security.removeProvider(provider.getName());
   java.security.Security.insertProviderAt(provider,3)
  
 } 
  public ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory(){
  KeySTore keystore = KeyStore,getInstance("Luna");
  InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("path/to/keystore");
  keystore.load(inputStream,"password".toCharArray());

  SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create()
                       .loadKeyMaterial(keystore, 
 "password".toCharArray())
                       .loadTrustMaterial("pathTocacert", 
  "password".toCharArray())
                        .setProtocol("TLSv1.2")
                        .build();

   }
   @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
      return new RestTemplate(requestFactory());
     }
}
```

I am not sure this code is going to work. I have done a lot of google and then found how we can create a SSL context with Luna client.
If someone has done it before Please provide some guidance.

Comment: Can someone please reply and help me on this.

Comment: I have not done this, but my understanding is that you need to have their java sdk and use that.  Do you have it?

Comment: @AlwynSchoeman, I am already using their LunaProvider.jar.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry I can't help you using the java api.  I need to use it over a socket and I don't use the certificate stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like a KeyStore. See below

```
@Service
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class HsmService {

  public KeyStore hsmKeyStore(String hsmPartition, String hsmPassword) throws
KeyStoreException,                                                                   CertificateException,                                                                       NoSuchAlgorithmException,                                                                       IOException {

    LunaProvider lunaProvider = new LunaProvider();
    Security.addProvider(lunaProvider);

    LunaSlotManager lunaSlotManager = LunaSlotManager.getInstance();
    lunaSlotManager.login(hsmPartition, hsmPassword);


    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Luna");
    keyStore.load(null, null);
    return keyStore;
  }
}
```

Once you have a keystore, you can do all of your standard crypto operations on it.